# Node traverse in Xml using MSXML

Tags: attributes, msxml, xmlnode

i am trying to traverse a node attributes ..in below xml ,i need to attach a new node in attribute value '1'or'2'matched.. how can write a code for that using MSXML property..help me 
i.e browse xml through attribute ...

```
<data>
    <menu id="**1**">
        <existes>01</existes>
    </menu>
    <menu id="**2**">
       <existes>1</existes>
       <existes>2</existes>
   </menu>
    <  menu id="**3**">
    <existes>2</existes>
   </menu>
</data>
```

Comment: What exactly should appear after: "attach a new node in attribute valu", show sample pls.

Comment: data\1
if found '1' means append below a new node...here not considered 'menu' directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you know how to traverse nodes over document.
MSXML exposes for traverse IXMLDOMNode - you need cast it to IXMLDOMElement ( in c++ use QueryInterface in C# or VB just cast to expected interface).
IXMLDOMElement - has enumerable property 'attributes' - so you can iterate all attrs of element.